# using jQuery to update CSS class in a .html or .cshtml file, or CSS property in a .css file

Tags: jquery

What is the simplest jQuery solution for the following?:

1. Read absolute URL of loaded page
2. compare it to a developer provided-list of URLs
3. when a 'true' condition is found, do EITHER of following
    3a. change CSS class in a .html or .cshtml file
    3b. change property value of a class in the .css file

This is what I've tried so far (sorry about the formatting, it's my first time using SO):

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Get current url
var url = window.location.href;

// Specify URLs
var list1 = "link"
var newmsg1 = "link"
var dash1 = "link"
var root1 = "link"

// Compare URL
if (url === list1) {
$(this).html(this.html().replace('header-link-list-bold', 'header-link-list-normal'));
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a programing site. If you have tried something then someone can help.

Comment: Just asking a question. Pretty sure what I asked is legit, as it's a programming related question on a site for both professional and enthusiast programmers. Stack overflow agrees - this is their main heading on their site tour. stackoverflow.com/tour "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."